# Determining if a distribution is standard normal from a five number summary

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics

I'm reviewing material for an exam in statistics. Can anyone tell me why the answer to this question isn't C? In my view, the five number summary in C is clearly more symmetrical than D. Am I missing something here?

[image: "3. The options below each give the five number summary (minimum, Q1, median, Q3, maximum) for a variable measured on 100 observations. Which of these variables most likely follows a standard normal distribution? ... (a) -1.96, -1.645, 0, 1.645, 1.96 ; (b) -8.76, -2.71, -0.33, 0.77, 1.22 ; (c) 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0 ; (d) -1.76, -0.73, 0.01, 0.83, 2.70 "]

Comment: This is a slightly different scenario, but worth mentioning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we can't tell that the distribution *is* from a standard normal. We can sometimes tell that it isn't. The most we can hope to do is say that it's reasonably consistent with having come from a standard normal.

The question you've been given there is perhaps not a particularly well-considered question from several points of view (there's subtleties to it that they'd need to deal with pretty carefully), but I'll try to address what it is getting at:

1. Symmetry isn't the only consideration. For example, it asks about a standard normal. What's the mean and standard deviation of a standard normal? [Indeed the chance that *none* of the 100 observations are on one side of 0 will be incredibly small, roughly on the order of $10^{-30}$. (c) is more like a five number summary from an extremely large sample from a standard-uniform-distributed population.]
2. some asymmetry in a sample from a symmetric distribution is to be expected -- if it was perfectly symmetric that would actually be surprising! Even if we take the values to have been rounded to the figures shown, symmetry of that degree would be rare without tens of thousands of observations.
3. Regarding (a) note also that the expected largest and smallest values in a sample of 100 from a normal are typically more than 1.96 standard deviations from the mean -- one might fall inside that range but it would be unusual for both to be (considerably less than 1% chance). You would also not expect the quartiles to be way out at $\pm$1.645 -- they should be nearer to about 0.67 ish. Actually, the quartiles being so far out is considerably more surprising.

Exactly one of the five number summaries looks consistent with a sample of size 100 from a standard normal.

Indeed here's 1000 five number summaries for samples of size 100 from a standard normal (transparent-ish grey dots), against their expected values and showing the four five-number summaries from the question:

[image: plot of 5 number summaries for actual normal and question values]

Comment: If this were Reddit, I'd give you Silver and Gold!

Comment: In using "most likely," the question is precise and has a unique answer.

Comment: @whuber I suspect that a reference to *likelihood* wasn't actually the intent of that phrase though.